# How to embed a project inside another project?

Tags: java, android

I have a source code for android project and I want to integrate and embed this app inside another app ...

In other words, I need to mix 2 apps with different packages inside one app ...

Thanks for your help and waiting your review..

Comment: You can import the second app to the first as a module.

Comment: Thanks.. but the second app is having different package name ..

Comment: Can I still edit the code if I import it as module ?

Comment: Yes, you can...

Comment: Can we contact... I need your help sir

Comment: Yes, we can....

Comment: Please tell me how we can connect

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by "mixing two apps":

- If you want to store the two projects in the same repository, you can do that without any problems.
- If you want to have them in the same project to be able to edit them at the same time, why not open them both simultanously in two separate windows? When opening the project, Android Studio will ask you whether you want to open the project in this window or in a new window. Just click "New window" and you will be able to edit the projects side by side without any fancy mixing going on.
- If you wish to reuse the code from one project in the other project, consider [creating an android library module](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library). That way, changes in the common code will automatically be reflected in both projects whereas when you copy-paste the code, you will have to copy changes back and forth, too.